# Alchemy4Tridion: Add a Container around a Control in an ExtendedArea with Apply.ToView

Tags: a4t

Taking my first steps with a4t, I am converting existing GUI extensions to a4t plugins.

In one of the extensions, this configuration popups up

```
<ext:extension assignid="SchemaFieldPropertySearchableContent" name="SchemaFieldPropertySearchableContent">
    <ext:control>~/Plugins/ACVCSC/assets/controls/SchemaFieldPropertySearchable.ascx</ext:control>
    <ext:pagetype />
    <ext:apply>
    <ext:view name="SchemaView">
        <ext:container name="SchemaDesignFieldDesigner">
            <ext:control id="AfterMandatory" />
        </ext:container>
    </ext:view>
    </ext:apply>
</ext:extension>
```

When I convert this to a4t, I have

```
public SchemaFieldPropertySearchableContentExtendedArea()
{
    //Properties
    AssignId = "SchemaFieldPropertySearchableContent";
    Control = "SchemaFieldPropertySearchable.ascx";
    EditorExtensionTarget = "CME";
    Name = "SchemaFieldPropertySearchableContent";
    PageType = "";

    //View 
    //TODO: How to set the container SchemaDesignFieldDesigner???
    Apply.ToView(Constants.Views.SchemaView, "AfterMandatory");            
}
```

In the Apply.ToView method, there is no parameter available to set the "Container". However, the tooltip on the Apply class reads "Gets or sets the apply instance that allows the extension to be applied to particular views, controllers or containers".

Any ideas on how to set the Container?

Thanks!!